# can't save the edited html in a website

Tags: html

I changed my profit amount in a live trading game with firebug but I can't save the amount which I changed.When I buy or sell the stock the profit is going back to the live rate,if there is any way for saving the changed amount ?

Comment: Fierbug changes are local only, and they last until website is reloaded.

Comment: he tried to cheat in a web game by modifying scores from firebug...and asks why it doesn't work.. it's not the place!

Answer (score 2):

Not from Firebug. You are just editing the in-memory DOM of the page.

If you want to make it persist in your browser then you'll need write a browser extension that will modify the page every time you load it.

If you want to make it persist for everyone then you'll need to change the server to send the updated data. This could mean anything from just editing a file on the server to writing some server side code that can accept a request (over HTTP) to change data in a database and then use that data to generate the page each time it is loaded.